# brcmfmac, brcmfmac_module_init No platform data available

Tags: wifi, kernel-modules, broadcom, sdio

I've update my kernel version from 4.11 to `5.4.3-g9c2490ac8-dirty #3 SMP PREEMPT Sun Aug 8 12:11:16 UTC 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux`

I have an issue with brcmfmac kernel module. I have enabled brcmfmac debug and enables all messages types in debug message.

you can see the dmesg output when I put this command `insmod /<path to ko file>/brcmfmac.ko debug=0x1FFFF`
:

```
[ 2526.159218] brcmfmac: brcmfmac_module_init No platform data available.
[ 2526.168959] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe Enter
[ 2526.168979] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe Class=0
[ 2526.168991] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe sdio vendor ID: 0x02d0
[ 2526.169001] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe sdio device ID: 0xa962
[ 2526.169011] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe Function#: 1
[ 2526.169347] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe Enter
[ 2526.169362] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe Class=0
[ 2526.169372] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe sdio vendor ID: 0x02d0
[ 2526.169383] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe sdio device ID: 0xa962
[ 2526.169392] brcmfmac: brcmf_ops_sdio_probe Function#: 2
[ 3249.364285] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_exit Enter
```

I don't see wlan0 name when execute `ifconfig -a` !

I have placed appropriate `.bin` and `.txt` files in path `/lib/firmware/brcm/`

```
ls /lib/firmware/brcm/ -l
-rwxr--r--    1 root     root        219557 Jun  2 12:28 brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
-rwxr--r--    1 root     root          1121 Jun  2 12:28 brcmfmac43362-sdio.txt
```

Comment: Did it work before you changed kernel?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue resolved.
I have add compatible property to usdhc in dts file.

```
&usdhc1 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    max-frequency = <50000000>;
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usdhc1_alt>;
    bus-width = <4>;
    no-1-8-v;   /* force 3.3V VIO */
    non-removable;
    pm-ignore-notify;
    cap-power-off-card;
//    /delete-property/ wakeup-source;
    status = "okay";

    brcmf: bcrmf@1 {
       reg = <1>;
        compatible = "brcm,bcm4329-fmac";
    };
};
```

as I remember the older version of brcmfmac was not sensitive to this property.